# Can I change the birth year when creating a pro?

Tags: fifa-14

I'm starting a career and creating a new pro. It asks me to fill in basic information like *First Name*, *Surname*, etc.

Two fields are disabled with a padlock next to them. The first one is *Team*, that one is set to the team I picked so it's fine. The second one is *Birth Year*, it's set to 1994.

Is there a way to change this?